# Configuring launch.json, task.json and settings.json for debugging in VS Code with git bash as default terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-bash, vscode-debugger, vscode-tasks

**I am trying to configure the Debugger in VSCode**

I looked through [official documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1Rcs.png) to setup the VSCode debugger for C/C++ but it's not working.

> Documentation states the steps for setting up vscode **debugger** for
> **powershell** in windows.

But I am trying to set-up **debugger** with **git bash** as my default **integrated terminal** in windows.

I have added **git bash** as default terminal but I am not able to setup **debugger** with git bash as integrated **terminal**.

**Default configuration files** :

***launch.json***

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++.exe - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

The *property* :

```
"externalConsole": false
```

is set to ***false*** as I want VSCode to use the integrated default bash terminal instead of using external terminal for debugging.

***tasks.json*** :

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

***c_cpp_properties.json***

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x86"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

***settings.json***

```
{
    "files.associations": {
        "iostream": "cpp"
    },
    "C_Cpp.errorSquiggles": "Disabled"
}
```

With the above *configuration*, when I start the debugging it gives me the following error:

[image]

It seems like the **command** property in **tasks.json** is incorrect,
as bash converts

> "**C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe**" -> "**C:MinGWbing++.exe**"

and gives ***error: "no command found***" because back-slash('\') in bash is an *escape character*.

Now changing above path in ***tasks.json*** to bash style :

> `"command": "C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe"`

resolves the above error, but now it gives same error for variable `${file}` as this path-variable gets dynamically set to current open file ***.cpp***.

[image]

I have been working on this debugging issue for last few days, but haven't found any workaround yet.

How can I *change/update* by **configuration files** to use **git bash as default integrated terminal** in VSCode for ***debugging***.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems like the command property in tasks.json is incorrect, as bash converts
>
> ```
> "C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe" -> "C:MinGWbing++.exe"
> ```

Then try a cygwin-like path:

```
/c/MingW/bin/g++.exe
# or
/C/MingW/bin/g++.exe
```

Check if it is interpreted correctly by the git bash session then.

Comment: Yeah it will surely resolves the compiler path error but then it gives same error for the  path variable ${file} in tasks.json, as this path variable also uses backslash to separate directories. 
Updated error.

Comment: @tusharRawat I wonder if WSL wouldn't be better suited than cygwin for that (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/1694#issuecomment-386485147)

Comment: yeah WSL might work, but just to use the linux terminal like experience (via git bash), I don't prefer installing the complete WSL for windows. There must be some workaround to use git bash as a terminal in windows.